# Deleting a pivot table in Excel; no gridlines remaining

Tags: excel, vba

I've deleted a pivot table in code by first selecting it, and then pressing delete. The area that the pivot table occupied is now not displaying gridlines. All other cells in this sheet are displaying gridlines. I have googled this problem, and several suggestions have been mooted in response to similar questions. These include:

- Navigate to Page Layout tab, and click on View Gridlines.
- Navigate to File / Options / Advanced, and ensure Gridline Colour is set to Automatic.
- Select the affected cells, and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to format the cells. Go to the Border tab and ensure that none of the borders are active.
- Select the affected cells, navigate to Home tab on the ribbon, and set the Colour Fill option to No Fill.
- Ensure that there is no conditional formatting on the spreadsheet.

None of the above work. However, if I copy and paste a cell from an unaffected area of the spreadsheet to the affected area, the gridlines then become visible. This is not an ideal solution though.

Can anyone help?

I can't seem to attach a version of the spreadsheet to this post.

Comment: `pivot table in code` - what is this?

Answer (score 1):

A cell does (simplified) contain a content and a format. By using `ENTF` key you clear content. If you want to delete both there is two ways:

By VBA:

You need to clear Formats on the range as follows:

```
Range("your Range").ClearFormats
```

The format remains because you have used `clearContents` by just deleting

Use `Range("Your Range").Clear` to delete both content and format

Without VBA:

See the picture below and select `ClearALL` in the Menu

[image]

Comment: If the answer was helpful, I would appreciate it, if you would accept it as correct @mediaevil

Answer (score 0):

Select the area where your PivotTable used to be, and then go to "Home" > "Editing" > "Clear"  ([Alt],[H],[E],[A])

You have deleted the contents of cells, but not the cells themselves, not the special PivotTable formatting.